# How to detect current Geo location and save in variable in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm developing an asp.net web app and i need to detect the current Geo location and save it to a variable and than show to user its current place name and through this I will guide the user to where he want to go, and than user will in put the destination and I will guide that what the root will be suitable for him and I will provide full detail.

I'm getting its current location but don't how to show to user by displaying on label or in textbox.

I don't know where to start this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to access the current geolocation of the user then you need to do the following things-

1. **Get Destination**
   Now you need to get the destination name from the user using some mode of text input or, speech to text etc.
2. **Geo Code destination**
   Now you need a good geocoding API to get the coordinate of the destination that user has entered. You can use [google's geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start). It is available for both client(JavaScript) and server(C#, Java, PHP -etc) side. All you need is an API key.
3. **Find Route**
   Now you have to find the route between the two coordinates (your current location and destination coordinates). Google provides a [direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) for the same. Again you can implement this both on the client or, server side (I will prefer client side to reduce the load on the server end). This API returns a long polyline string which can be decoded into a list of coordinates to plot the route on the map. It also returns a list of maneuver data containing the direction info and road names etc. This maneuver info will help you to direct your user to the destination at the time of navigation.
4. **Plotting the route**
   Now is the time to add a map canvas to your application and then plot the route to it. You can now use the list of coordinates that you decoded from the polyline to draw a polygon on the map. See this below screenshot from one of my application where I drew the path on the map and also marked all the maneuver points on the path.[image: It will look something like this]
5. **Navigation**
   Well, now you are almost done. Now you can start navigating to the destination. Now use whatever mechanism you use to get the user location periodically and then update it as a marker (you can use a car's icon) on the map and then whenever you reach (calculate the distance) a maneuver point show user the maneuver message like "Turn right"/"Turn left"/"Continue straight for 100 meter" -etc.

If you are stuck with getting the current user's location then you can use [HTML5](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b19d5a/geolocation-in-html5-using-Asp-Net/) to get devices location using the network.

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your article is very helpful for me. i m pleasured. Can you please tell me the working demo, it will be better understandable for me. However Thanks, Thanks aging. Stay blessed!

Comment: Hi @GhulamMujtabaKhan If this is helpful for you then you can mark this answer for this question and upvote if you like. I will share the demo with you later.